# What does '**' in Ruby do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What does the `**` symbol mean in Ruby?

```
(1..5).map { |i| i**2 } # => [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: I dont know ruby, but seems like exponential to , isn't?

Comment: Isn't it obvious from the output?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, no lol

Comment: @railsr Sergio is asking you to do a little bit of thinking first. I know it's hard, but consider this `1**2 = 1`, `2**2 = 4`, `3**2 = 9`. What operation does that look like? Exponential!

Comment: Let's see, a quick Google search for "ruby **" returns links. The first is http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm. The third is http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html. Both directly describe what `**` is. Please take the time to research your questions. That is a prerequisite for questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: OK. I got it. Sry for that.

Comment: I don't get why people are so quick to down vote! I get that the question might be obvious for some, but I find this downvoting thing is just like bullying someone in class because his/her question was obvious.

Comment: @Anna: asking obvious (to others) questions is one thing. Not doing proper homework before asking is another.

Answer (score 8):

[`Fixnum#**`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-2A-2A) is the exponent operator. In your example, you are squaring `i` (raising it to the power of 2).

Comment: Documentation: [`Fixnum#**`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-2A-2A)

Answer (score 2):

I have never used Ruby, but from the results I infer that `i**2` means `i^2` (that is, `i*i`):

- `1*1 = 1`
- `2*2 = 4`
- `3*3 = 9`
- `4*4 = 16`
- `5*5 = 25`